# RTK Query, Query with body to Post endpoint

Tags: rtk-query

I would like to know if it is possible to use a RTK Query to target a POST endpoint. I must call a REST endpoint to get data but it accept a body and POST request only...
I managed to do it using a mutation but problem is that I did not find a way to avoid calling API multiple time by using cache ( the call is in a react useEffect that get triggered when component mount). Basically, I would like to call this POST endpoint and use cache when Query parameters doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries can also be POST requests, there is no difference in the syntax between queries and mutations - returning a string from a query or mutation is just a shortcut for returning `{ url: "...", method: "GET" }` from a query or mutation, so you can do the same with a `POST` request.

```js
const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    // ...
  }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    searchPerson: build.query({
      query: ({ name }) => ({
        url: `person`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: { search: name  },
      }),
```

But make sure that the POST doesn't actually change something on your server. Queries should just retrieve data, not modify any.

Comment: Is there a way to identify the method in prepareHeader of fetchBaseQuery for query ?

Comment: @Alex_K from the back of my head, I think no

Comment: I find a way by passing extraOptions to the baseQuery

Answer (score 0):

Async state management libraries like RTK Query and React Query typically lack caching for mutation operations. in your case since the POST request is not mutating any resource you can treat is as a GET request and use a query hook istead of mutation hook.